# What would aliens find disturbing about Bible-Belt Christianity?

Tags: aliens, psychology, firstcontact

Say that an alien race makes first contact with Earth. They orbit for a few days, take a look around... and then land right in the middle of the Bible Belt.

Provided that they have moral values similar to [the Race,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Race_(Worldwar)) what would they find most disturbing about Christianity?

*Nota Bene*: This is not a Cowboys-and-Aliens situation like the Worldwar series. While the aliens may be appalled at us they are not actively attacking us, nor are we attacking them.

Comment: Given that there are many different opinions on Bible-Belt Christianity among the residents of the Bible-Belt, let alone the rest of the world why would you expect the opinions of an alien race to be any less diverse?

Comment: I don't know the race enough for an answer, but wikipedia says "Due to their seasonal breeding cycle, the Race does not form nuclear family units the way humans do. Given that breeding is just a biological imperative during mating season, they also don't form bonds of romantic love between males and females, so human literature and art about romantic love strikes them as perverse.". Family is quite important in christianity, so that could be a start

Comment: honestly, I don't see how this is different from the already closed question: it is still opinion based AND a duplicate

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica How is this opinion-based? I gave very clear criteria about the kinds of answers I am looking for, and I did use the Psychology tag. As for the bit about duplication, I added quite a bit of clarifying detail that the other one was missing.

Comment: It's opinion based because even among our own species there's a vast number of different opinions of how disturbing (or how reassuring) Bible-Belt Christianity is. Another species opens up the possibility for an even broader range of opinions about the religion. As such basically any opinion with 2 sentences of supporting arguments is a valid answer.

Comment: Also from a possible list of things that they MIGHT find disturbing you want to point to MOST disturbing thing. Right from the bat some might say it's that god is not Emperor while other might argue that it's looking up and not down. And so many more.

Comment: By the [Bible Belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_Belt), I assume that you mean the states of Alabama, Georgia, Mississippi, North Carolina, South Carolina, Tennessee, Texas, Virginia and West Virginia in the United States of America? Those are dominated by (neo-)evangelical Protestant denominations; not typical of world-wide Christianity by any means. Most Christians have only a very vague idea about the values and beliefs promoted by those denominations. (And those vague ideas are mostly collected from movies and serials, and may have a tenuous relationship with reality.)

Comment: For what is worth, running to accept an answer on a downvoted question with VTC doesn't send a positive message on how convinced you are about your own arguments on "this is a good question"

Comment: FWIW, I think this is a really interesting question... even if I can't argue against it being opinion-based. I probably *ought* to VTC as a duplicate, because yes, it's also a duplicate, but I'm also somewhat disappointed to not see it answered.

Comment: @Matthew It's a fascinating question. It's just not a good fit for this site. P.S. If you feel that it is a duplicate please VTC, and don't answer. It sends conflicting signals.

Comment: @sphennings, that's exactly why I *didn't* VTC...

Comment: @Matthew What I'm trying to say is please prioritize VTC over answering.

Comment: @sphennings, there's a Meta question there. I'm not saying that we don't need some degree of order, but preferring to shut down questions seems counterproductive to the purpose of the site. I think it's an interesting question that could have interesting answers. I would rather see those answers than see it closed, and I have acted accordingly.

Comment: Fascinating question, but you lack focus. There are a lot things that non-Evangelicals might find disturbing about Bible-belt Christians and their beliefs, to say nothing of ill defined aliens. You really need to focus this query on your own worldbuilding. Define your aliens and their worldview. Then define which Christians in the Bible-belt you want them to be considering.  Otherwise, all answers will be meaningless and your green checkmark will be given in vain.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica It is an extremely good answer, therefore I decided to accept it, with the logic that I could always accept a different answer if a better one were to be submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the "obvious".

According to the Bible, God created Man in his own image. More importantly, God created Man to be *perfect*, but Man sinned, and God cursed the whole creation (i.e. whole universe) as a result, but promised redemption through Christ (the same Christ from which Christianity derives).

If this is true, and *especially* if your aliens are mortal and/or aren't self-evidently perfect (and their mating habits certainly argue against it from a Christian perspective), well, now they have quite the quandary. Have they all been going to Hell this whole time? Do they need to convert to Christianity? Are they actually instruments of the Devil (which might mean they should try to destroy humanity)?

I'm not even getting into some of the more extreme, "fundamentalist" views that many *humans* find disturbing; I'm just talking about middle-of-the-road Christianity (i.e. people that take their beliefs a bit more seriously than the average so-called "Christian" that isn't, really, but also aren't as extremist as some of the fundamentalist sects).

On the one hand, the existence of such aliens would constitute a fairly strong argument that Christianity is bunk. (What the *lack* of existence of extraterrestrials in real life implies is left as an exercise to the reader.) On the other hand, you could have a lot of fun with tweaking either your aliens or their history to make them Christian-compatible, as was done in C. S. Lewis's [Space Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Trilogy).

Answer (score 2):

Anything to Nothing.

Remember that Christianity was created by Christians.
They are humans and they do feel that everything in the Bible is holy and normal, they accept everything written inside the Bible or sometimes they decide what they want to believe from the things writen in the Bible.

Christians find absurd the people that don't hold their same beliefs, other Christians don't agree with different Christians that don't follow the Bible to the letter or that use a different Bible with different translations.

A lot of atheists find the Bible to be absurd, work of fiction or ridiculous. Yet atheists are humans too.

Now if aliens have the same type of intelligence or something similar to humans that enables them to communicate with us then they might understand.

Because either they believe in something similar and they all believe in one religion,  they are split between religions and atheists too or they are all atheists.

Either way they will have a concept of religion as it is something that develops in every culture.

Rituals are born out of coincidence and become religion, therefore any creature can become religious if their intuition is wrong.

Example: pigeon in test lab presses a button, the scientists give the pigeon food... Now the pigeon will believe the button to be a "give me food instantly" button, and even when the scientists stop giving the pigeon food, they will continue pressing that button over and over and over again.

That is the same concept of religion, prey continuously and sometimes by pure confidence your preyers will come true, now your belief that a god grants you free wishes if you prey is even stronger so you will continue, even when it doesn't work because eventually... Maybe it will work again.

Answer (score 0):

As with the *fithp* of *Footfall* (by Larry Niven and Jerry Pournelle), one of the most baffling things about humans -- *any* humans, not just those in the Bible Belt -- might well be that we have strongly held social rules that we enforce on each other and then individually ignore.

Monogamy.  Honesty.  All of our immense and self-contradictory body of law.

We simply don't or can't follow our own rules.  For an alien race that thinks with anything resembling our brand of logic, but didn't grow up with us (for that matter, for *some of us*) this is inexplicable and nonsensical.  Why have rules if almost no one actually follows them?